# Chrome shortcut for selecting web content

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Chrome (on OS X) to let me select the web page content? Sometimes after I go to a web page I want to start scrolling using my space bar but it gets stuck in a textbox or in the address bar, etc. I can hit tab many times to get to the web content but it'll cycle through all my toolbar and menu items first.

[Google's website](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650) lists this for the Windows version. I'm looking for something similar on the Mac side.

> **F6** or **Shift+F6**
>
> Switches focus to the next keyboard-accessible pane. Panes include:
>
> - Address bar
> - Bookmarks bar (if visible)
> - The main web content (including any infobars)
> - Downloads bar (if visible)